# Is there a way to use google voice on magic jack on linux?

Tags: linux, wine, google-voice, magicjack

I am running the latest Ubuntu. Here is what I want to achieve:
I want to be able to dial a number on the phone on my magic jack, and connect the call via google voice. I have tried running GV jack under wine, with no such luck. I know I can buy a magic jack number, and add my magic jack number to google voice, but I don't want to pay for magic jack so I can use my free google voice number on my phone.